# Can we use life cycle method in function component? vise versa life cycle hooks in class component?

Tags: reactjs, methods, react-redux, react-hooks, components

can we use the life cycle method in the function component? Does vise versa life cycle hook in-class component? If yes, How, Please Share any link on same.

Comment: no you can't use stuff for class component in function component etc. more https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Rajendra Singh Adhikari, If the below answer is useful kindly approve the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the life cycle method in the functional component with help of `useEffect` hooks.

`useEffect` hook can be used to replicate lifecycle behavior. For example:

**componentDidMount:**

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('unhandledRejection', handler);
}
```

> Equivalent in functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('unhandledRejection', handler);
}, [])
```

**componentWillUnmount:**

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    alert('The component is going to be unmounted');
    window.removeEventListener('unhandledRejection', handler);
  }
```

> Equivalent in functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('unhandledRejection', handler);
    return () => {
       alert('The component is going to be unmounted');
       window.removeEventListener('unhandledRejection', handler);
    }
}, [])
```

**componentDidUpdate:**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     const { counter } = this.props;
     if (this.props.counter !== prevState.counter) {
      // some action here
     }
}
```

> Equivalent in functional component

```
useEffect(() => {
     // action here
}, [props.counter]); // checks for changes in the values in this array
```

Comment: Hi @Rajendra Singh Adhikari, I am glad you found my answer helpful :) If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks